# Why my Android app keeps getting rejected by Google play console saying account deletion link doesnot link to a valid page?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have included the account deletion link in the data safety form but the app keeps getting rejected on same issue.

```
Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: “URL provided 
https://admin.meetleelou.com/leelou/deleteaccount does not link to a valid page”
```

I couldn't figure out what i'm missing.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic